# Resources on modern WCF

Tags: wcf

I am looking for resources on best practices when working with WCF these days as compared to how things were done in the distant past (~2012).

I am working on some codebase that has quite the history and would like to figure out if there is anything to improve on the WCF side of things.

Comment: That is an incredibly broad question.  What specifically are the things that you think need to be improved, and why do you think that?  WCF has not changed that radically since it came out with .NET 3.0.

Comment: @Tim yes I know, the 2nd part is good to hear so I guess just the general "new stuff from various .net versions" applies (like async) and nothing much special to watch out for, right?